# c# windows shutdown control

Tags: c#, windows, service, shutdown

**Please read - this is not a duplicate**.

I have a Windows service that runs under the LocalSystem acct.  I am in need of restoring certain files prior to shutdown.  I am able to intercept the Shutdown action at which point I initiate my restore process but the shutdown happens before I am able to complete.
I have enabled Shutdown privileges, added calls to AbortShutdown (Win32) and several other (ie shutdown /a) options but they do not work.  I believe it is because the shutdown or restart has already been initiated and I have read that these functions only stop a shutdown while it is scheduled.

My goal is to intercept the shutdown, abort it, complete my tasks and then shutdown.  I just need more time and the amount of time is dependent on the number and size of files I have to restore.

I am open to any suggestion and appreciate your time and consideration.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your goal is untenable. On Windows, the user has control over the shutdown process. If the user wants to shutdown the machine, it's not up to your software to contravene the user's intentions.

The burden is on you to make sure that your software can deal with a shutdown, whenever it happens. This usually means making sure that file operations are as atomic as possible, or using a "hot journal" file to recover (on the next system startup) in the event that atomic operations can't be completed.

The files that you speak of, that you have to restore before shutdown, should be "restored" (hard to tell exactly what you mean here) as soon as any operations are finished on them. Without further details, it hard to discuss the specific approaches.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds more like something that can be done with windows batch files.